# date and time picker problem, can't reset date or time

Tags: c++, visual-c++, controls, dialog, datepicker

I'm using a usoft date time picker control in a dialog box.  I started by setting the format to "HH':'mm' 'ddddMMMdd','yyyy" and the current local date & time using DTM-SETSYSTEMTIME. If the user changes any field in the control, the program can not reset the date and time in the control using DTM-SETSYSTEMTIME although SendMessage returns a 1.  As far as I can tell, the dialog box returns false (zero) to any notifications it receives concerning the control.

The problem as described above is how I first became aware of it but it's actually much simpler.  I did two DTM-SETSYSTEMTIME calls in a row and only the first one took affect. The second in the following example does not get put into effect even though the status is returned is 1.

```
        hwnd = GetDlgItem (hDlg, IDC_SUN_STAT_DATE_TIME);
        Status = SendMessage (hwnd, DTM_SETFORMAT,0,(LPARAM)"HH':'mm' 'ddddMMMdd','yyyy");
        Status = SendMessage (hwnd, DTM_SETSYSTEMTIME,GDT_VALID, (LPARAM)&systimeTime);
        systimeTime.wHour += 2;
        Status = SendMessage (hwnd, DTM_SETSYSTEMTIME,GDT_VALID, (LPARAM)&systimeTime);
```

It appears that only the first DTM-SETSYSTEMTIME is put into effect, following ones are ignored.

What do I have to do to change/reset the date/time in the control? Or (more likely) what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, what language and framework?

Comment: @Skurmedel: visual c++ 6.0, I can retrieve the modified date/time but I can not set a new one, the control remains frozen at whatever the user did.

Comment: I tried handling the DTN-DATETIMECHANGE and returning zero with SetWindowLong (hwnd,DWL_MSGRESULT,0), that causes the date time in the control to be set to blanks. Am I supposed to copy the SYSTEMTIME found at NMDATETIMECHANGE .st someplace?

Comment: Okay :) I retagged it if you don't mind. Having a language tag will make it show up in unanswered and will likely get you help quicker.

Comment: I mean, it will highlight under language tags in unanswered, because I think many people monitor specific tags.

Comment: Is Usoft still around?  Have you tried contacting their technical support?  This is a VERY specific question on VERY old technology, so it might be difficult to get a good answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have cut and pasted your code into my own program in Visual C++ 6.0, and it works perfectly for me. If I comment out the second DTM_SETSYSTEMTIME, I get a time that is two hours earlier. There is something in the code you're not showing us.

**Edit:** Since you've selected this answer, I might as well make it accurate. I've verified your comments with my own program.

You're having a problem with the interactions of unexpected behaviors of the date/time picker:

1. The SYSTEMTIME structure requires a full 4-digit year.
2. The date/time picker does not indicate an error if you use DTM_SETSYSTEMTIME with an invalid SYSTEMTIME.
3. Once you've set an invalid SYSTEMTIME, the date/time picker stops responding to further DTM_SETSYSTEMTIME messages. Furthermore it still returns as if it had processed the message properly.

Comment: Thanks! Knowing that it works for you in the same environment allowed me to figure out what I did wrong. The problem turned out to be an illegal year in my SYSTEMTIME which I had constructed from a tm time (I neglected to take the 1900 offset into account). Evidently DTM-SETSYSTEMTIME accepts an illegal year (and substitutes the current year) if it has no date/time BUT ignores subsequent calls with illegal years. If DTM-SETSYSTEMTIME has given me an error or failed entirely, I would have figured this out long ago.   Happy holidays!

Comment: Well, to be complete DTM_SETSYSTEMTIME accepts the first illegal SYSTEMTIME and ignores subsequent illegal ones BUT will later respond to proper SYSTEMTIMEs.